# TFS 2015 On Premise REST API 404 searching test runs or results

Tags: rest, tfs-2015

Using the TFS 2015 REST API to try to get test runs and results with 404. When fetching projects or teams it works fine.

```
var uri = $"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/project/_apis/test/runs/1994/results"; 

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var result = wc.DownloadString(uri);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
Console.Read();
```

The following URLs do not work:  (NOTE: I removed the server portion because of a limitation of stackoverflow)

.../tfs/project/_apis/test/runs

But these do work:

.../tfs/project/_apis/projects/CodedUi/teams
   .../tfs/project/_apis/projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **wrong url**, lack of team project collection name.

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/Yourcollection/project/_apis/test/runs/1994/results?api-version=1.0
```

And since there are two versions of API *1.0,3.0*, suggest you also add the related API version. More details please refer this tutorial: [Get a list of test results](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results_1_0#get-a-list-of-test-results)